# Listing of places nearby

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

How can I access the returned results of a places search? I just need a select-able listing as in the places check-in from facebook

Answer (score 0):

Try using Places Autocomplete of the Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API v3:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

An example can be found here:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete